# background-image behind and in front of a shade divider

Tags: background-image, shapes, divider

Hi I would like to make a bg-img wirth landscape and a truck in front of it. over this I would like to have a diagonal black line with "shade divider" and then I like to have the truck from behind in front overlapping half the shade divider. Can someone explain this to me? i work with oxygen builder.

Thank you.

I tried with shape divider but never was the truck in front of the shape.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have some code to share? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.